# Having issue parsing span value from web page with python/robot framework

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework, ui-automation

Hey I feel like this should be fairly simple but for the life of me I cannot get this to work. The scenario is a such
I am trying to write a keyword or a series of keywords that will get the text of a dynamically generated value. The values appears after `<span class="ng-binding>"`

Here is the HTML Tree

```
<li class="list-group-item">
                    <label class="">Tracking/SR Number:</label>
                    <span class="ng-binding">70498018 <!-- ngIf: vm.serviceRequest.siebelSrNum --><span ng-if="vm.serviceRequest.siebelSrNum" class="ng-scope">/</span><!-- end ngIf: vm.serviceRequest.siebelSrNum --> 1-2093674326</span>
                </li>
```

For debugging purposes I tried `xpath =//*[text()='Tracking/SR Number:']  get text`
and it returns "Tracking/SR Number" as expected

But `xpath = //*[text()='Tracking/SR Number:']//following::span[1]` nor `xpath = (//span[@class='ng-binding'])[2]` will return the  value *70498018*, /, *1-2093674326*, or  *70498018 / 1-2093674326* . (It appears as one text value on the UI)

I've double checked with xpath creation tools and the correct element highlights when I use either of these but when I try to `get text` the value returned is an empty string.

I tried to do some google/stackoverflow foo and cannot come across this specific example. Does anyone know why the get text function would return a empty string for this element? I've tried get value as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake on the path, the span elements are not children of the label, but of the li element. I have tested with the following code:

```
${spans}=    Get Webelements    xpath=//*[text()='Tracking/SR Number:']/../span
Log Many    ${spans}
${mytext}=    Get Text    ${spans[0]}
Log    ${mytext}
```

Got the output:

```
20170617 01:13:58.423 :  INFO : ${spans} = [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0668007-68d0-408e-89ab-a86f97f8e8ed", element="96ced152-7a08-4b6e-94af-d4cced3e7ecd")>]
20170617 01:13:58.432 :  INFO : [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0668007-68d0-408e-89ab-a86f97f8e8ed", element="96ced152-7a08-4b6e-94af-d4cced3e7ecd")>]
20170617 01:13:58.633 :  INFO : ${mytext} = 70498018 / 1-2093674326
20170617 01:13:58.643 :  INFO : 70498018 / 1-2093674326
```

Comment: I tried your method and got this:  '_KEYWORD BuiltIn . Log Many ${SRDetailPageTN/SRnumberText}
Documentation: 
Logs the given messages as separate entries using the INFO level.
Start / End / Elapsed: 20170616 15:55:15.568 / 20170616 15:55:15.569 / 00:00:00.001
15:55:15.569_ **INFO [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4ba22004880a1ca358f637708c857616", element="0.21525661230973392-15")>]'** @Hello

Comment: So it's just a matter of getting the text like in: *Get Text    ${spans[0]}*